# Spacy for Python not returning tokens

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to run a simple code using SPACY nlp but not getting anything back for labels.
Please help?
My code is blow. I am not getting any output from print statements.

```
from spacy.lang.en import English
nlp = English(entity=True)
doc = nlp('John Smith loves coding in Python!')
for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_)
print([token for token in sent if token.ent_type_ == 'PERSON'])
```

Comment: Just use `nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` and you will see some results.

Comment: Can you use another model, or do you need to make it work with the `from spacy.lang.en import English`?

Comment: do you get empty line, or empty list `[]` or error message? these can be different problems.

Comment: your code gives me error message: `NameError: name 'sent' is not defined`. If you also get this error then you should show it in question from the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @WiktorStribiżew said in comment - code works for me when I use

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

I also had to download file

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

You may also download it in code

```
spacy.cli.download('en_core_web_sm')
```

but because you need to download it only once so downloading it in code is waste of time.

---

BTW: It should be `doc` instead of `send`

---

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp('John Smith loves coding in Python!')

for ent in doc.ents:
    print(ent.label_)
    
print([token for token in doc if token.ent_type_ == 'PERSON'])
```

---

Frankly, similar code you can see even on [scapy web page](https://spacy.io/)